# Error: loop in R of each column?

Tags: r, loops

I have some data and trying to do analysis. I dont know how to use R but I watched few videos on internet and trying to mimic the same test I need. What I want to do is trying to compare first four (1-4) rows with next four (4-8) rows. After I get result, I want to apply the same test to next column, therefore I will have 4 different p values. Please find an example image attached [attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/moLrW.png). I have 4 columns in total which is the pilot test and will be performed with large column sizes later on. May I ask if someone can tell me what I am doing wrong and edit the code. I would be very glad for all helps.

```
Test = matrix(c(120, 115, 132, 117, 116,117,125,120,110,113,128,115),ncol=4, nrow = 4)
Test=t(Test)

Drug = matrix(c(88, 80, 85, 85, 83,84,90,83,83,79,86,82),ncol=4, nrow = 4)
Drug=t(Drug)
mydata<-cbind(Test,Drug)


for (i in 1:4)
wilcox.test(mydata[i,1:4],mydata[i,5:8], mu=0, alt="two.sided", paired=T,  conf.int=F,conf.level = 0.99, exact=T,correct=T)
```

Comment: I ran your code, and it works. You do get some warning messages about ties. Is that your problem?

Comment: @KoenV, no, the problem is that loop is not working. It is giving warning and not calculating anything. If I delete for loop and changing "i" to 1 or 2 or 3... it works but I want to do in a loop instead of writing numbers to column place.

Comment: @KoenV what I want to do is using "i" as a loop so it can give 4 different p values. To make it clear it will be comparison between these sets: **mydata[1,1:4]-mydata[1,5:8]** , **mydata[2,1:4]-mydata[2,5:8]** ,  **mydata[3,1:4]-mydata[3,5:8]** ,  **mydata[4,1:4]-mydata[4,5:8]** . So I don't want to change the column numbers every time but I want to use loop or something which automatically goes to next column and recalculate .

Comment: The R way of doing this would be a `data.frame` with one column containing measured values, a second column specifying e.g. compound (test/drug), and a third column specifying some kind of grouping (representing the rows in your data, e.g. group A, B, C etc). Then `dplyr` or `data.table` can be used to perform group-wise tests (i.e. per A, B, C etc.) and `wilcox.test` takes a formula argument which would be e.g. `value~compound`.

Comment: @KristofferWintherBalling your solution is more than accepted sir. Thank you very much. I want to ask another question. If I have 100 columns like these 2 groups, should I write 20 different letters? For 3 different columns, you wrote A,B,C but for huge amount of column numbers, is there any short way for it ? Sorry for repeating the same question below since I couldn't find a way to mention your name there. +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using a `data.frame` or `data.table` for this with a column specifying groups (corresponding to rows in the example, e.g. A, B, C), one column specifying test/drug and one column with values:

```
library(data.table)
Test <- c(120, 115, 132, 117, 116,117,125,120,110,113,128,115)
Drug <- c(88, 80, 85, 85, 83,84,90,83,83,79,86,82)
groups <- rep(c(rep("A", 4), rep("B", 4), rep("C", 4)), 2)
variable <- c(rep("test", length(Test)), rep("drug", length(Drug)))
dt <- data.table(group = groups, variable = variable, value = c(Test, Drug))

# >dt
#     group variable value
#  1:     A     test   120
#  2:     A     test   115
#  3:     A     test   132
#  4:     A     test   117
#  5:     B     test   116
#  6:     B     test   117
#  7:     B     test   125
#  8:     B     test   120
#  9:     C     test   110
# 10:     C     test   113
# 11:     C     test   128
# 12:     C     test   115
# 13:     A     drug    88
# 14:     A     drug    80
# 15:     A     drug    85
# 16:     A     drug    85
# 17:     B     drug    83
# 18:     B     drug    84
# 19:     B     drug    90
# 20:     B     drug    83
# 21:     C     drug    83
# 22:     C     drug    79
# 23:     C     drug    86
# 24:     C     drug    82
#     group variable value
```

Testing test-values vs drug-values per group is then a matter of:

```
dt_stat <- dt[, .(p_value = wilcox.test(value~variable, mu=0, alt="two.sided", paired = TRUE,
  conf.int = FALSE, conf.level = 0.99,exact = TRUE, correct = TRUE)$p.value),
  by = .(group)]

# > dt_stat
#    group    p_value
# 1:     A 0.09751254
# 2:     B 0.09751254
# 3:     C 0.12500000
```

Comment: You Sir, saved my day. Thank you very much. I want to ask another question. If I have 100 columns like these 2 groups, should I write 20 different letters? For 3 different columns, you wrote A,B,C but for huge amount of column numbers, is there any short way for it ? +1 +1 +1 +1

Comment: You are welcome. You can just use numbers (e.g. 1 to 100) instead of A, B, C.

Comment: Is there a way to do it in a loop, sir? I mean even with this I am very fine to use but if there is a short cut instead of writing 1 to 100 I would be more than glad. Thank you again for your great help.

Comment: For this example, I didnt use CSV file, I manually wrote it. But I can read a csv fileand  prepare in csv as well.

Comment: For the real data can you provide the structure of the csv you are reading (I hope you a not typing ~800 numbers by hand). Is it like the matrix in your question?

Comment: It will prepared by matlab to me so I am not going to type it will be matrix indeed 2x100. First row represents test and second row will be drug.

Comment: @JamesBurton May I ask another question, we set the groups based on if they are including same amount of numbers. **Test <- c(120, 115, 132, 117, 116,117,125,120,110,113,128,115)** and **Drug <- c(88, 80, 85, 85, 83,84,90,83,83,79,86,82)**. **groups <- rep(c(rep("A", 4), rep("B", 4), rep("C", 4)), 2)**. This works perfectly, but, for instance, if I have to neglect one of the number in Drug values lets say **Drug <- c(88, 80, 85, 85, 83,84,90,83,83,79,86)** (last number **82** is removed), in this case it will be 4,4,3 values in the columns. Is there anyway to set this into this code? should